# Looking for Platform SDK SSPI(Schannel) sample c++

Tags: c++, sample, sspi, schannel

I want to see a microsoft sample that demonstrate using of SSPI with Schannel.
As I see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is a such sample, but I cannot succeed to find it :(
Can anyone please help me to find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2642/SSL-TLS-client-server-for-NET-and-SSL-tunnelling) is written in C++/CLI

Comment: @Harvey Kwok: no. I want the Microsoft sample..., do you know how can I obtain it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are WebServer and WebClient examples in [Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK ISO Install](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15656) under `Microsoft Platform SDK\Samples\Security\SSPI\SSL`.